# Count the number of existence of a specific number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, counting, countif

I have multiple cells which have number separated by columns and want to count the number of existence of a specific number. How may I count the number. what will be the formula.
I have data like in picture and want to count the existence of 1 or any other number in all highlighted cell. I used the countif formula to count the number 1 but it also counts it for 11 or 12.
If anyone have any Solution.
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezz0t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try and restructure your data so it's easier to work with. Otherwise, here's a *dirty* solution:

You could first add a comma before and after all your cells with "," & cell & "," so all numbers are separated by a comma, including the last one. Then use COUNTIF to count numbers, by looking for eg. ***,1,*** or ***,12,***:

| Orginal | ="," & A1 &"," | =COUNTIF([your cell range];"*,1,*") |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,2,10,11,12 | ,1,2,10,11,12, | 4 |
| 1,2,10,11,12 | ,1,2,10,11,12, |  |
| 1,2,10,11,12 | ,1,2,10,11,12, |  |
| 1,2,10,11,12 | ,1,2,10,11,12, |  |

Comment: Yup this will help. But I would like to see a good solution.